# C++ Динамический Массив

Tags: c++

Не очень понимаю как реализовать дин.массив на CPP.
Нужно что-то похожей на это :

```
a = []

n = int(input('Количество элементов'))

for i in range(n):

    a.append(int(input()))
```

Comment: `std::vector`...

Comment: Добавлю: `std::vector::push_back`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
   int *a, N;
   cout << "Input N = ";
   cin >> N;
   a = new int[N];
   for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
   {
      cout << "Input a[" << i << "] = ";
      cin >> a[i];
   }
   //.... действия с а
   delete a;
}
```

Comment: А если нужно будет ввести тип string? как изменится код

Answer (score 0):

1)) new/delete Почти как в си malloc/free.

2)) В C++ это делается так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    int N;
    cout << "Input N = ";
    cin >> N;
    v.resize(N);
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Input a[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> v[i];
    }
}
```

new/delete(malloc/realloc/free) лучше не использовать. Обычно от этого больше проблем чем пользы.

3)) Ещё есть такое:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "Input N = ";
    cin >> N;
    int v[N];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        cout << "Input a[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> v[i];
    }
}
```

В MSVC через _alloca
В каждом из 3 вариантов есть свои минусы:

1. Запросто можно получить memory leak, segmentation fault
2. Работает довольно долго в Debug, сложный шаблонный класс.
3. Запросто можно получить segmentation fault, stack owerflow

Comment: А где вы увидели, что 3) появилось в с++14? не знал, что так можно

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/

Comment: А точнее? Просто, насколько мне известно, в стандартном с++ нет никаких VLA, они есть только в каких-то фичах определенных компиляторов

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/184606/
https://smartbear.com/blog/develop/a-glimpse-into-c14/
например

Comment: Если вы про dynarray, то он так и не вошёл в стандарт

Comment: https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf страница 184-185 
у меня в компиляторе работает и ладно

Comment: у 2 варианта проблемы с отрицательными числами, 3 вариант невалидный в стандартном цэ++

Comment: Я не собираюсь делать из примера DynArray Enterprise Edition. Для msvc можно извернуться и сделать _alloca а в 2 других компиляторов VLA доступны. Это 3 основные возможности доступные в C++: статически, в куче, на стеке.